# Как вывести ListView с картинками из базы данных SQLite?

Tags: android, json, sqlite, listview, android-asynctask

В приложении Android есть база SQLIte, в которой хранятся данные в 4 столбцах, по примеру: "_id", "https://example.com/dataimage/136.970.jpg", "text1", "text2". 
Естественно, данные в каждой строке относятся друг к другу. Нужно из этих данных собрать ListView, чтобы каждый пункт содержал в себе свою картинку из колонки, где указан адрес картинки, типа - "https://example.com/dataimage/136.970.jpg".

Выводить из SQLite cursor и собирать адаптером text1 и text2 это просто, а вот как быть с картинками?

Адрес картинки, а также text1 и text2 я получаю из json, распарсивая его AsyncTask и записывая в SQLite.

Прошу вас просто намекнуть мне - где искать, и как это проще реализовать. 
Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам нужна одна из библиотек для загрузки-кэширования-отображения картинок из сети. Например UIL или Picasso

В первом случае код будет такой:

```
ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance(); // Get singleton instance
imageLoader.displayImage(imageUri, imageView);
```

Во втором так:

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```